# Subtracting the difference between two string variables

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I have two strings containing time, like this:

```
  'ftime1' => string '17:44' (length=5)
  'ftime2' => string '18:19' (length=5)
```

I need to calculate the difference between frime2 and ftime1, so result is in **minutes**.

I have tried

```
 $struct[$i]['ttime'] =  time($struct[$i]['ftime2']) - time($struct[$i]['ftime1']);
 $struct[$i]['ttime2'] =  strtotime($struct[$i]['ftime2']) - strtotime($struct[$i]['ftime1']);
 $struct[$i]['ttime3'] =  $struct[$i]['ftime2'] - $struct[$i]['ftime1'];
```

Which result in:

```
  'ttime' => int 0
  'ttime2' => int 2100
  'ttime3' => int 1
```

Comment: `time()` does not do what you apparently think it does. It doesn't even take arguments! http://php.net/time

Comment: really, as decez basically says, RTFM... time() has no arguments and simply returns the current timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` converts string into timestamp which is on seconds..so the difference will also be in seconds..do `/ 60` for minutes..

```
(strtotime($struct[$i]['ftime2']) - strtotime($struct[$i]['ftime1'])) / 60;
```

and time function does not  behave that way, it returns current Unix timestamp, and doesn't take any argument..